# WPF: How to join business object and DataTemplate or ControlTemplate in a CustomControl

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

I'd like to create a CustomControl in WPF to present one to many items to the user in a certain manner.

For that I created a CustomControl with a dependency property `ItemsSource` and a dependency property `ItemsTemplate`. But I'm not sure how to join the business objects from the `ItemsSource` with the `DataTemplate` or `ControlTemplate` so that I have something WPFy to measure in the `MeasureOverride` and to place in the `ArrangeOverride`.

Do I use something like a `ContentControl` for each item and put my business object as `DataContext`?

Thank you for any advice or any push in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of googling and spying on the ItemsControl of WPF I think I have to use a `ContentPresenter` for each item which isn't a `DependencyObject` itself.